# Are Pixie's magic powers part of her mutation?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

The mutant (Megan Gwynn) learnt a teleportation spell from Magik, another mutant. Is her ability to learn/perform magic part of her mutation or something 'extra' and not related to the X-gene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Her magical ability is not a mutant power, but it is related to her genetics.**

Pixie (Megan Gwynn) is a hybrid mutant and fairy and possess powers granted to her both by her mutation and inherit magical abilities. Since both of her powers come from her genetic heritage, she would have her physical abilities which would be her X-gene and her magical potential from the fairy side of her family.

The Marvel Wikia indicates her *magical* abilities are:

> **Spell Casting:** Pixie has innate magical aptitude, Doctor Strange has promised to teach her more spells when she turns eighteen. Pixie
>   was one of the many possible candidates for the title of Sorcerer
>   Supreme.
>
> **Teleportation:** After the creation of her Souldagger, Darkchylde taught Pixie a teleportation spell, "Sihal novarum chinoth!" With this
>   spell, Pixie can transport her and others great distances
>   instantaneously. She can also teleport inter-dimensionally. The limits
>   of her teleportation spell have not yet been determined.
>
> **Demons Banishment:** Using the spell from the Cheyennes magic book she was able to banish the demons.

Judging from her being considered as a candidate for the title of Sorcerer Supreme, she must have considerable magical potential if not current aptitude. The ability to learn both long distance teleportation and inter-dimensional teleportation is quite a feat. And if Stephen Strange, the previous Sorcerer Supreme has offered to teach her, he must consider her worthy of further instruction.